# encrypted flash of DSP

Tags: flash, dsp

when programming the flash of DSP by accident i encrypt the flash content.
is there any way to decrypt flash of a **DSP**? the flash was encrypted.

Comment: I suspect it will depend on the DSP in question and how you program it. Do you have a JTAG interface?

Comment: Why can't you just erase it and try again?

Comment: because i do not have the source for code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were programming the device then you must have source non-encrypted code. Why not re-flash again with non-encrypted code?

However if it is DSP allowing you to flash its code, and now you flashed with encrypted contents and DSP can not start properly (because it does not understand contents of the flash) then the only appropriate course of action is to refer to DSP's datasheet to learn how you can perform emergency flash content reload. You may need special tools (e.g. adapter) to perform it.